# weighted ARIMA in R or other software

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am using the forecast package in R to do time series forecasting. I have a history of 5 years and want to predict the next 3 months.  I've noticed that if I only use the 2-3 most recent years in my training set the prediction is better than using all 5 years.  I believe this is because patterns the ARIMA algorithm finds 5 years ago are no longer applicable for predicting the future.

Instead of completely eliminating data from long ago, is it possible to just weight these less?  Currently there is no such option in forecast, but is there a way to hack this, or are there alternative software packages?

Comment: I think that this might be a better question for cross-validated.  Though, one thing that works particularly well in these situations is model averaging. In it's most simplest form, build two models. The first will use data from the most recent two or three years to estimate the model parameters; the second will employ the full data set. Once you have the two forecasts, combine them.  There are many advanced techniques, but a simple average often works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weighting is really more for when you have had a change in the variance and identified using Tsay's test.

It sounds like you could use a "level shift" variable (ie 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,).  This will allow you to still keep the seasonality and the day of the week effects in tact, but also react to the the change in mean.  You should also be looking out for changes outliers, changes in trend and changes in seasonality as Mondays may be low and become high.  You should also be considering holidays with lead and lag impacts, day of the month impacts and long weekends.

Ruey Tsay followed up on Box and Tiao's work with outliers as you can read here www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf

Since you asked - Our software is called Autobox and does these things automatically and was launched in 1976.
www.autobox.com

Answer (score 0):

The Chow Test which is also incorporated in AUTOBOX actually dteremines if any of the parameters have changed ober time. If as you assert the last 2-3 years has a different ARIMA structure than the prior periods AUTOBOX will suggest data segmentation. If you want to pursue this feature contact the folks from Aautomatic Forecasting Systems. By the way I have written those procedures for them.